# Number of processes killed by pskill

Tags: sysinternals

Can you clarify for me what I'm seeing when using pskill to kill a remote process on a domain PC?

I have written a small, .exe file in VB.NET that runs on a remote PC that simply loads a web page and saves a value to a database for me. I have written this application to be a "Single Instance Application" to prevent multiple instances running at the same time.

When I run my pskill command against that machine, I get the following result:

> c:\SysInternals>pskill -t \PCNAME MyApp
>
> PsKill v1.15 - Terminates processes on local or remote systems
>   Copyright (C) 1999-2012  Mark Russinovich Sysinternals -
>   www.sysinternals.com
>
> 1219 processes named MyApp killed on PCNAME.

I've modified the App name and PC name above.

Why is it saying 1,219 processes named "MyApp" were killed? Are "processes" in this context different than "instances" of the application? Is this normal? Some PC's running the exact same application will return only 1 or 2 "killed" processes, some "56", etc. Seems to be a random total of processes being killed.

Just want to understand what is happening as I don't want that many instances of the application running remotely.

Comment: This has nothing to do with vb.net.

Comment: Application was written in VB.NET - so it was included in case that is part of why the process total is that high.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with VB.Net. You are running a command from VB.Net. But that has nothing to do with what pskill is doing, just like it doesn't matter what brand keyboard you used to type this question.

Comment: The application that is being "pskilled" was written in VB.NET, so yes, it does matter. Your comment isn't very useful...